# Multithreaded use of one RInside Instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, rinside

I am trying to make a RInside call from within multiple threads, and am encountering this error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Error evaluating: qnorm(.65, mean=0,sd=1)
```

The line of code that causes this is :

```
//within main.cpp//
std::shared_ptr<RInside> R = std::make_shared<RInside>();

//within some_class::some_function(std::shared_ptr<RInside> R)//
double value = Rcpp::as<double>(R->parseEval("qnorm(.65, mean=0,sd=1)"));
```

R is a std::shared_ptr that is being shared between 80+threads.
I am assuming that this issue is a locking issue, as the RInside instance is busy executing the first parseEval when another one comes in.

Am I right in my assumption? 
Thanks!

Comment: This has been discussed at length before: you simply cannot have a multi-threaded context around R.

Comment: Thank you. I will make all R interfacing sequential.

Comment: If you go multi-_process_ you can make things work. One of the earliest contributed examples in the package the `mpi/` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a lightweight wrapper for the RInside instance. Lets multiple threads safely use the instance. Change the return type of use and the templated argument to Rcpp::as<>, and pass around RInside_Container with a shared_ptr.

```
class RInside_Container{
    double use(string command_to_execute){
        mtx.lock();
        double value = Rcpp::as<double>(R.parseEval(command_to_execute));
        mtx.unlock();
        return value;
    }
    Rinside R{};
    std::mutex mtx;
};
```

Thanks Dirk